# Static Instance of Class null on calling?

Tags: java, static, instance

I have a class with a static instance of itself (the one instance used universally throughout the code,) but, when I call on said instance, it is null. How can this happen? This is what I'm talking about:

```
public class A{
  public static A instance = new A();
  private A(){
  }
  public void method(){}
}

public class B{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    A.instance.method();     //Here, I am getting a NullPointerException.
  }
}
```

How can this even happen with `instance` being static and self-instantiating?

Comment: This won't compile - There's no type for "instance".  Shouldn't it be of type A?

Comment: My bad. In a bit of a rush.

Comment: Do you import the right A class?

Comment: i tried your code, no **NPE** for me. and instnace is definitely not null.

Comment: It does not seem possible. Have you recompiled your classes?

Comment: No NPE here, either. Did you perhaps simplify the code in such a way that it eliminated the true issue? (I don't imagine you discovered this error using `A` and `B`.)

Comment: A.instance = null somewhere in your code? May be not thread safe?

Comment: @assylias I am using Eclipse. I don't understand why it's happening. Perhaps it's important to say that I am not the original author of most of the code, but I have searched through the code (with Eclipse's handy searching tools) and have found nothing that sets the instance to null.. I'm clueless..

Comment: @Eric I'm not entirely sure. I've looked through the code and haven't found anything causing a problem.

Comment: @jdb That might be it.. Hadn't really thought of that.

Comment: Seriously, it worked for me...

Comment: You can download the project file here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/jovob8dnui0xkix/AppJav.rar